# How to create the Map using Java8 Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How to update the Map using java 8 streams ? As for now I am doing :

```
        Map<String, Integer> testMap = Maps.newHashMap();

        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> testEntrySet : testCounts.entrySet()) {
            String name = Utils.cleanName(testEntrySet.getKey());

            if(testMap.containsKey(name)) {
                testMap.put(name, testMap.get(name) +
                        testCounts.get(testEntrySet.getKey()));
            } else {
                testMap.put(name, testCounts.get(testEntrySet.getKey()));
            }

        }
        return testMap;
    }
```

Comment: Side comment: `testCounts.get(testEntrySet.getKey())` ==> `testEntrySet.getValue()`...

Comment: What does `Utils.cleanName(…)` do? In your source map, the keys are unique, so the complicated merging logic is unnecessary, unless `cleanName` can produce ambiguous names out of the formerly unique keys. You can replace your loop logic with `testEntrySet.forEach( (key,value) -> testMap.merge(Utils.cleanName(key), value, Integer::sum));`, but if you insist on a Stream usage, go for assylias’ answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tested it but I suspect your code is equivalent to:

```
return testCounts.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(e -> Utils.cleanName(e.getKey()),
                            summingInt(e -> e.getValue())));
```

(with the appropriate static `Collectors` imports).